# How can I find Python Built-in functions?

Tags: python, built-in

I went through python 2x and 3x docs. It only mentions the following -

> The Python interpreter has a number of functions and types built into it that are always available.

How and where are these built-in methods free floating?

Comment: in the Lib folder .... (for most of them) ... the ones that are built into python itself can be browsed by checking out the source on github

Comment: "since python is OO based" Nope.

Comment: Python supports the OO paradigm but does not impose it. You can write in a plain procedure style or even functional, etc.

Comment: Python is **not** OO-based. It *supports* OO, but that does not make it OO-based.

Comment: "everything should be defined inside objects" nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not object oriented based,it can also be functional.However if you want to look for the functions and their methods you can type in the interpreter

```
>>>dir(__builtins__)
```

This gets a list of built-in functions and variables in the directory,also you can use work around by typing

```
>>>help('module')
```

or

```
>>help(function-name)
```